# Reading ints line from a file in Python

Tags: python

I have to list a integers from a text file separated by newlines into a python list. I ended up with the code above which works (for my case) but certainly is far form optimal.

```
def readIntegers(pathToFile):

    f = open(pathToFile)
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    tmpStr = ""

    integers = []

    for char in contents:

        if char == '\r':
            integers.append(int(tmpStr))
            tmpStr = ""
            continue

        if char == '\n':
            continue

        tmpStr += char

    return integers
```

---

Now I have much less code, but I'm not sure for which cases split() works correctly.

```
def readIntegers(pathToFile):

    with open(pathToFile) as f:
        a = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]
    return a
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need for `split` (you can use [`readlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines)). But no need for `readlines`, for that matter:

```
def read_integers(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return map(int, f)
```

or, if that’s more to your fancy:

```
def read_integers(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [int(x) for x in f]
```

A `file` object is simply iterable in Python, and iterates over its lines.

Note that, contrary to what I said earlier, wrapping the file object in a `with` block is highly recommended. [Python doesn’t actually guarantee (although it recommends it) that objects are disposed of automatically at the end of the scope.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) Worse, it’s not guaranteed that a `file` object that is collected actually closes the underlying stream.

(Note that I’ve adapted the method name to Python conventions.)

Comment: Thx for your answer :) I didn't think of using map here.